# VCS Trigger in TeamCity not working

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I'm trying to get a VCS trigger to work in TeamCity with TFS but no matter what I do, I can't get it to trigger on a checkin

I've defined the VCS trigger as +:fodl/FODL.Database.InvestmentDataMart.APTExtract/**

..which I believe should only trigger a build if changes are detected in that directory but none of the pending changes every seem to trigger a build

Here's a screenshot of my build trigger:-
[image]
And a screenshot of my build source directory where all files have been checked out to:-

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can't use checkout rules to target just the FODL.Database.InvestmentDataMart.APTExtract folder as all the solution files all live in the base directory above it (FODL)

Comment: Important part here is whether you actually see the changes in TeamCity UI (as pending). If yes - then it's the triggering rules which need a tweak, if no - you need to check/change the VCS root settings and checkout rules (if any).
Plus, it makes sense to double-check the case of the path/filenames in the repository (e.g. as seen in the pending changes) and in the trigger settings as TeamCity expects it to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try `+:**/fodl/FODL.Database.InvestmentDataMart.APTExtract/**`. If the disconnect is "where I think the root directory is" versus "where TC thinks the root directory is", the prepended wildcard should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is obvious or not, but the VCS trigger only let's you control if the build will run and what rules will trigger the build. The VCS trigger does not do anything if TeamCity is not aware of the change in the source control repository. For that you need to either

- Define a scheduled trigger that will change for changes in your source repository.
- Or configure TFS to notify TeamCity (through web hooks or other kind of integration) that there is a change.